# Blockchain app won't let me send bitcoin because it says there's nothing in the wallet, yet I have $40 in there

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet

Like the title says, it won't let me send any bitcoin through the "Send" function of the blockchain app, and only prompts me with the "Buy Crypto" button, but I have $40 in the wallet. I bought it through the app, and even got email confirmation about the amount I bought, and it says "Now available in wallet." Could anyone help with this?

Comment: You ask "Could anyone help with this?" -- have you asked Blockchain.com for help? What did they say?